# get a list of local and network printers with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0, printing

I have a web application with asp.net 2.0 and I want to create a dropdown menu showing the printers installed on the client machine? How is that possible?

I tried the following code

```
foreach (string strPrinter in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
   // add to list
}
```

but it shows only the local printers attached with the server, not the client machine.

Comment: There is a pretty hacky way that a lot bad guys are using, I am not sure whether it is reliable and don't wish going into details about that. Take a look at Jeremiah grossman's blog and you will find the my referred approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get it in ASP.NET because that's running on your server. You can't get it in Javascript either. It's just not available; see, for example, http://javascript.about.com/od/events/a/print_3.htm.

The only solution I can think of is to build an ActiveX control, and you then you could use the C# you have in the question, except running on the client. Of course, that limits you to IE.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the installed printers on client machine, then you might have to use the javascript as the code you have written will be executed on server side.